# Why 0 results on "where not in" query

Tags: mysql, where-in, mysql-5.6

```
mysql> show columns in m like 'fld';
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| fld   | varchar(45) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> show columns in i like 'fld';
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| fld   | varchar(45) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> select count(distinct fld) from i;
+---------------------+
| count(distinct fld) |
+---------------------+
|               27988 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> select count(distinct fld) from m;
+---------------------+
| count(distinct fld) |
+---------------------+
|               72558 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.07 sec)
```

The above results seem reasonable based on what I know of the tables in question.

```
mysql> select count(*) from m where fld not in (select fld from i);
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.11 sec)
```

That last result does not seem reasonable. [There must be](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) *some* rows in `m` with `fld` not in `i`! Can someone please explain why I get `0` as the result?

---

For completeness (because I suspect it may be relevant), I'll also paste this result:

```
mysql> select count(*) from m where fld is null;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

**Edit:** In reply to comments, I'm editing in the following info also, in case it helps someone answer my question:

- `select count(*) from m join i using (fld)` yields 9350; with `left join`, 73087; with `right join`, 28872.
- `select count(*) from i where fld is null` yields 810.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've now figured it out. [The documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) reads:

> To comply with the SQL standard, `IN` returns `NULL` not only if the expression on the left hand side is `NULL`, but also if no match is found in the list and one of the expressions in the list is `NULL`.

Thus, `fld not in` (i.e. `not fld in`) returns `not null` (i.e. `null`) whenever there's a `null` in the derived table (which there is here) and `fld` isn't found in the derived table (which is what I'm testing for).

---

There may be a better workaround than this, but I'm using `(select fld from i where fld is not null)`.

Comment: True. Weird behavior. Maybe there's a good reason for this, but so far I've only seen errors due to this, and no advantages. This is not just in MySQL by the way.